# How can I print the call stack of Java and Kotlin methods in real time using Frida?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reverse-engineering, frida

I have an android application firefox fenix (firefox for android), I also have its source code. I need to find the place where this application makes a request to download any files. I use Frida for this, but I don't understand how I can find this function, Frida doesn't give me the function calls I need. Help me write the right script, or use the right tool to look through the call stack and find the function I need.
I tried to use frida-trace but using it I only get .so libraries. And I would like to see clear paths to Java methods, since the code is not obfuscated.
I also tried to write a script using chatgpt that displays the stack of all calls, but it turned out to be incomprehensible, a lot of calls to js files, no java methods.
But several times it was possible to display something similar to java classes, but they were displayed once at the beginning, and that’s it, nothing else was displayed, no matter what I did with the phone.

Comment: Have you considered that the code you search is buried so deep that there is no Java code related to it? You can write Android apps that nearly completely base on C or similar code and only uses marginally parts of Java/Kotlin. May be you should edit your question and include details on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I just need to display the stack of calls of functions of the Java classes of my application, and that’s all so that they are in an understandable form, where the name of the class and the function that is called are displayed in real time